# How to enter Pose mode with Linked Armature?

Tags: linked-data, pose-mode

So, I've made several assets to use in a project all in their respective files. Some of them have armatures on them. But when I try to link these objects, I can't enter Pose Mode, in fact, the option doesn't even exist.

Is it not possible to animate linked Armatures in Blender? Must they always be appended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method for this varies depending on the version of Blender, but yes it can be done.  For version 2.8 and more recent, the recommended approach is:

The *Library* file is the file that you will be linking *from*.  In it, create a collection containing both the armature and the mesh.  When you link, link the collection, not the contents.

Once you have linked, you need to configure the setup for posing.  In theory, you could use a *library override* in all instances, but in 2.8x, *proxies* are less buggy and I recommend a proxy for 2.8x and a library override for 2.9 and later.

To make a proxy, as soon as you link the collection, select the object and then from the Object menu select Relations -> Make Proxy.  From the drop down that appears select the armature.

To make a library override, ass soon as you link the collection, go to the Object Menu in the 3D Viewport and select Relations -> Make Library Override.

The Blender manual describes [proxies](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/files/linked_libraries/library_proxies.htm) thusly

> Proxies are the historical way in Blender to allow some local editing of linked data-blocks. This is mostly aimed at character animation.

The manual describes [library overrides](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.htm) so:

> Library Overrides is a system designed to replace and supersede Proxies. Most types of linked data-blocks can be overridden, and the properties of those overrides can then be edited. When the library data changes, unmodified properties of the overridden one will be updated accordingly.

The transition from proxy to library override has been a bumpy road.  Library overrides were very buggy in 2.8, became better in 2.9, and are slated to completely replace proxies in 3.1.

In either event, for armatures, "limited editing" includes posing, so if you want to pose an armature that you linked from a library you have to use this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however, could you explain what you mean by Proxies or Libraries override? What are their use exactly?

Comment: @Filnisius see my updated answer.  Proxies/overrides are used to allow posing in the case of armatures.  In the case of meshes they are used to allow moving and resizing the mesh

Comment: Thank you for the information. This answer was exactly what I needed. I never tried linking things before, so the explanation on what proxies and overrides are, are also very welcome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.